# Cron executing PHP: 416 error

Tags: php, cron, wget, http-status-codes, dreamhost

I'm running a cron job through the dreamhost panel. The site is using basic HTTP Authentication.

```
wget --http-user=[user] --http-passwd=[pw] http://www.example.com/script.php
```

It worked the first time it ran, but since then I get this result:

```
--2013-10-23 00:00:01--  http://www.example.com/script.php
Resolving www.example.com... [ip] Connecting to     www.example.com|[ip]|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required Reusing existing     connection to www.example.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.
```

I don't understand 416 errors, and I'm not sure what to make of the "file is already fully retrieved" line. All I can think is that since it's reusing an existing connection it doesn't want to actually run the script again, so maybe I should get it to log out after each time it runs, but I don't know what I'm talking about. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I havent used Dreamhost but my guess is that your original result is getting cached in the server. Can you check with your provider if the wget has been customized? If you own example.com/script.php you could try and test another page or another user for --http-user. If you do own the example.com/script.php you should also check the apache logs there to see the request when you execute wget.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after keeping tabs on this for a while it looks like the cron job is actually working just fine. The PHP script it accesses is making some API calls, checking for new content on a third party server, and importing any fresh content to my database. When there is no new content to import, that's when it throws the 416 error. Weird.